# App will crash when i pressing Submit Button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

App will crash when I pressing Submit Button. Before that View Controller, I will hide the navigation controller. From that view controller, I will show the navigation controller. I think there is a problem while I am using navigation controller. Please help me to resolve this.

IMAGE : 
[Storyboard View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhgWr.png)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

        self.tfName.delegate = self
        self.tfPhone.delegate = self
        self.tfEmail.delegate = self
}

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        //self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

        self.navigationItem.title = "Visitor Details"
}

@IBAction func btnSubmit(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if tfName.text! == "" || tfEmail.text! == "" || tfPhone.text == ""  || imgUser.image == UIImage(named: "chooseImage")
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController.alertCtrl(title: "Warning", message: "Please fill all the fields correctly.", buttonTitle: "OK")
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            if !(Utility.validatePhone(value: tfPhone.text!))
            {
                let alertController = UIAlertController.alertCtrl(title: "Warning", message: "Please enter your phone number correctly.", buttonTitle: "OK")
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                if !(Utility.validateEmail(candidate: tfEmail.text!))
                {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController.alertCtrl(title: "Warning", message: "Please enter your email address correctly.", buttonTitle: "OK")
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            let confirmUserVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ConfirmUserVC") as! ConfirmUserVC

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(confirmUserVC, animated: true)
            //self.present(confirmUserVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

            confirmUserVC.strImg = self.imgUser.image!
            confirmUserVC.strName = tfName.text!
            confirmUserVC.strPhone = tfPhone.text!
            confirmUserVC.strEmail = tfEmail.text!
        }
}
```

Error shows in the console :

> 2018-01-15 11:18:38.648960+0530 DE1[5465:138738] [MC] Lazy loading
>   NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework 2018-01-15 11:18:38.661549+0530
>   DE1[5465:138738] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework 2018-01-15
>   11:18:38.683557+0530 DE1[5465:138738] [MC] System group container for
>   systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/rahulchopra/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A51E4843-5A2C-4B97-837E-D30EDD015372/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2018-01-15 11:18:43.519861+0530 DE1[5465:138738] [MC] Reading from
>   private effective user settings. 2018-01-15 11:18:48.385343+0530
>   DE1[5465:138738] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy
>   constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
>   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active)>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2018-01-15 11:18:48.386778+0530
>   DigiEntry[5465:138738] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
>   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active)>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2018-01-15 11:18:50.587132+0530
>   DigiEntry[5465:138738] Can't find keyplane that supports type 5 for
>   keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-PhonePad; using
>   2024220450015396792_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Complex-Pad_Default
>   2018-01-15 11:19:18.659275+0530 DigiEntry[5465:138738]
>   [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active)>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2018-01-15 11:19:18.661432+0530
>   DigiEntry[5465:138738] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.     Try this:       (1) look at each
>   constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;          (2) find
>   the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active)>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

Comment: This log is about wrong auto layout constraint. Not about app crashed. When did your app crash? Show the log of crash instead of this?

Comment: Can you update your Log.. Just search "*** Terminating app due to " .. Paste that part.

Comment: add exception brake point and tell us where execution stop.

Comment: The exception is at :    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(confirmUserVC, animated: true)

Comment: When i am using self.presentviewController then it is Okay

Comment: Have you set navigationController as your `rootViewController`?

Comment: Yes i set UINavigationController as on root

Comment: How are you opening your current view controller from previous view controller. Post that code.

Comment: Recheck whether you have given the correct storyboard Identifier by selecting the view controller in Storyboard.